# CodeIgniter / MAMP Pro : mapping URI param to default controller

Tags: url, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, uri, mamp

I'm having an issue getting my rewrite rules to work. Here's what I get:

mysite:8888/ - works, but throws missing argument errors (expected)
mysite:8888/myvar - 404 error
mysite:8888/index.php/test/index/myvar - works and displays myvar on page (expected)
mysite:8888/test/index/myvar - 404 error
mysite:8888/test/myvar - 404 error

My routes.php file only contains:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "test";
```

config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite:8888/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

test.php (controller):

```
public function index($myVar){
  $data['myVar'] = $myVar;
  $this->load->view('test', $myVar);
}
```

test.php (view):

```
<h1>Test page</h1>
<p>Here's your variable: <?=$myVar?>.</p>
```

and here's my .htaccess file (not even sure I need one):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The goal is to have this URL:  mysite:8888/hello

Generate this: "Here's your variable: hello."

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried mysite:8888/test/myvar/?

Comment: I would bet your htaccess file isn't setup correctly - makes sense seeing that when you use index.php in the url everything works

Comment: Try RewriteBase / in your htaccess file just under RewriteEngine on

Comment: @Chumillas, yes I tried that, and received a 404 error.

Comment: @jpea - I just added that line, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. It turns out I had everything setup correctly, but the file headers on my .htaccess file were telling my Mac that it was a rich-text document. I pulled down a working .htaccess file from my web server, pasted the rewrite rules into it, and bingo! It started working. Thanks for the suggestion, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with rewrite on my mac the trick was to add

Options +FollowSymlinks

on the top of the htaccess file. Hope it will help cause i was getting access forbidden when i forgot to add.